# Byte Array to Double Array

Tags: java, types, fft

I have an array of bytes representing data from a .wav file. I want to convert it to an array of doubles, so that I can do operations such as FFT on it to determine whether one file is contained in the other.

Right now, I simply cast the bytes to doubles, which gives me decent results, but not as precise as I would like. I know this is improper conversion, and I feel like it is causing me to miss data, because of the difference in what bytes and doubles represent.

How can I convert the byte array to a double array properly before doing the FFT correlation?

Comment: How do you want to convert it to double? I mean if you have byte[] bArr; where size of bArr is 8, do you want to convert 8 bytes to 1 double, or do you want to convert such array to array of 8 doubles?

Answer (score 4):

If each byte actually represents a signed 8-bit sample value, then the data has been lost when the sample was recorded, and there is nothing improper or imprecise about casting to `double` (which *can* accurately represent all values that `byte` can) - there isn't really anything else you can do.